# Is it a common practice to run the `paginate` method inside a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to implement pagination using the [WillPaginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem. In order to keep the business logic in models I would like to know if it's a **common practice** to run the `paginate` method (related to the WillPaginate gem) inside a model.

Is this common practice or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No it is not**

Pagination calls should not belong in the model because it is strictly related to presentation. The implementation of the pagination could be in the model if you are writing your own pagination logic, but the calls to pagination should be in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

I generally place pagination logic in the controller action for the page. Any business logic complex enough to be worth the name should live in a model method that gets called from there.